# Read an email that's hosted on a webmail server?

Tags: c#, webmail

Can I view **and click a link** on an email that is hosted on a webmail server (I know the pass/user/etc) in C#? The link will always be the same, but it needs to be clicked from there.

I could always just put a webbrowser in and keep using invokeElement("click") but that seems very inefficient.

This is using a cPanel webmail, not gmail, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use a pop/imap library, parse the email, then open the link in a browser.